# How to deobfuscate native Android library obfuscated with OLLVM?

Tags: ida, idapython, android, obfuscation, deobfuscation

When I load the binay in IDA, all I can see are loads of `.datadiv_decodeXXX...` functions and this is because of OLLVM.  I know it is possible as a Chinese article I found said they were able to decrypt all the strings by using IDAPython.  I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you decide it is obfuscated with OLLVM? Found [something](https://blog.quarkslab.com/deobfuscation-recovering-an-ollvm-protected-program.html).

Comment: The `.datadiv_decode....` functions are a telling sign of OLLVM.

Answer (score 4):

You're in luck; I wrote an [article](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=1248) about that last year. I didn't know at the time that the obfuscator in question was Obfuscator-LLVM, but indeed, it was (albeit a version that was integrated into the MSVC toolchain). I even published [full source code](https://github.com/RolfRolles/HexRaysDeob).